# Simulating a hospital

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

I have a Java program which simulates a hospital. For this, I have two different databases, MySql and MS SQL, with tables to manage the patients. The user can decide which database he wants to use.

For each database type, I created a `PatientRepository` which implements my `PatientRepository` interface, both of which work with a JDBC template.

Because some of the syntax differs between these databases (for example, `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl_patient ORDER BY NEWID()` vs. `SELECT * FROM tbl_patient ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`) I wrote two implementations of `PatientRepository`. But I see there is a lot of redundant code, which I like to avoid.

`PatientRepository` implementations:

```
public class PatientRepositoryMSSqlImpl implements PatientRepository {

private JdbcTemplate template;
private PatientGenerator patientGenerator;


public PatientRepositoryMSSqlImpl(DataSource dataSource, PatientGenerator patientGenerator) {
    this.patientGenerator = patientGenerator;
    this.template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}


public void insertPatient(Patient patient) {
    template.update("INSERT INTO tbl_patient(lastname, firstname, gender, birthday) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
            patient.getLastname(), patient.getFirstname(), patient.getGender(), patient.getBirthday().toString());
}

public void insertListOfPatients(List<Patient> allPatients) {
    for (Patient patient : allPatients) {
        insertPatient(patient);
    }
}

public Patient getRandomPatient() {
    String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl_patient ORDER BY NEWID()";
    Patient patient = (Patient) template.queryForObject(sql, new PatientRowMapper());
    return patient;
}

public Patient admitRandomPatient() {
    Patient patient = getRandomPatient();
    patient.setDepartment(patientGenerator.getRandomDepartment());
    patient.setWard(patientGenerator.getRandomWard());
    patient.setAdmissionDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    patient.setStatus("I");
    template.update(
            "INSERT INTO tbl_inpatients(id, ward, department, admissionDate, patientStatus) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",
            patient.getId(), patient.getWard(), patient.getDepartment(), patient.getAdmissionDateTime().toString(),
            patient.getStatus());
    return patient;
}

public Patient getRandomInpatient() {
    String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl_inpatients ip, tbl_patient p WHERE p.id = ip.id ORDER BY NEWID()";
    Patient patient = (Patient) template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {}, new InPatientRowMapper());
    setPatientBasicData(patient);
    return patient;
}

public Patient setPatientBasicData(Patient patient) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_patient WHERE id = '" + patient.getId() + "'";
    Patient patientNew = (Patient) template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {}, new PatientRowMapper());
    patient.setLastname(patientNew.getLastname());
    patient.setFirstname(patientNew.getFirstname());
    patient.setGender(patientNew.getGender());
    patient.setBirthday(patientNew.getBirthday());
    return patient;
}

public Patient transferRandomPatient() {
    Patient patient = getRandomInpatient();
    patient.setPriorWard(patient.getWard());
    patient.setPriorDepartment(patient.getPriorDepartment());
    patient.setDepartment(patientGenerator.getRandomDepartment());
    patient.setWard(patientGenerator.getRandomWard());
    template.update("UPDATE tbl_inpatients SET ward = ?, department = ? WHERE id = ?", patient.getWard(),
            patient.getDepartment(), patient.getId());
    return patient;
}

public Patient dischargeRandomPatient() {
    Patient patient = getRandomInpatient();
    patient.setDischargeDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    insertFormerPatient(patient);
    template.update("DELETE FROM tbl_inpatients WHERE instance= ?", patient.getInstance());
    return patient;
}

public void insertFormerPatient(Patient patient) {
    template.update(
            "INSERT INTO tbl_formerpatients(instance, id, ward, department, admissionDate, dischargeDate) VALUES('"
                    + patient.getInstance() + "', '" + patient.getId() + "', '" + patient.getWard() + "', '"
                    + patient.getDepartment() + "', '" + patient.getAdmissionDateTime().toString() + "', '"
                    + patient.getDischargeDateTime().toString() + "')");
}

public int countPatients() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS numberOfPatients FROM tbl_patient";
    return template.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
}

public int countInpatients() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS numberOfPatients FROM tbl_inpatients";
    return template.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
}

public LocalDate parseBirthday(String birthday) {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(birthday);
    return localDate;
}

}
```

```
public class PatientRepositoryMySqlImpl implements PatientRepository {


    private JdbcTemplate template;
    private PatientGenerator patientGenerator;


    public PatientRepositoryMySqlImpl(DataSource dataSource, PatientGenerator patientGenerator) {
        this.patientGenerator = patientGenerator;
        this.template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }


    public void insertPatient(Patient patient) {
        template.update("INSERT INTO tbl_patient(lastname, firstname, gender, birthday) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
                patient.getLastname(), patient.getFirstname(), patient.getGender(), patient.getBirthday().toString());
    }

    public void insertListOfPatients(List<Patient> allPatients) {
        for (Patient patient : allPatients) {
            insertPatient(patient);
        }
    }

    public Patient getRandomPatient() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_patient ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        Patient patient = (Patient) template.queryForObject(sql, new PatientRowMapper());
        return patient;
    }

    public Patient admitRandomPatient() {
        Patient patient = getRandomPatient();
        patient.setDepartment(patientGenerator.getRandomDepartment());
        patient.setWard(patientGenerator.getRandomWard());
        patient.setAdmissionDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        patient.setStatus("I");
        template.update(
                "INSERT INTO tbl_inpatients(id, ward, department, admissionDate, patientStatus) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",
                patient.getId(), patient.getWard(), patient.getDepartment(), patient.getAdmissionDateTime().toString(),
                patient.getStatus());
        return patient;
    }

    public Patient getRandomInpatient() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_inpatients ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        Patient patient = (Patient) template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {}, new InPatientRowMapper());
        setPatientBasicData(patient);
        return patient;
    }

    public Patient setPatientBasicData(Patient patient) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_patient WHERE id = '" + patient.getId() + "'";
        Patient patientNew = (Patient) template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {}, new PatientRowMapper());
        patient.setLastname(patientNew.getLastname());
        patient.setFirstname(patientNew.getFirstname());
        patient.setGender(patientNew.getGender());
        patient.setBirthday(patientNew.getBirthday());
        return patient;
    }

    public Patient transferRandomPatient() {
        Patient patient = getRandomInpatient();
        patient.setPriorWard(patient.getWard());
        patient.setPriorDepartment(patient.getPriorDepartment());
        patient.setDepartment(patientGenerator.getRandomDepartment());
        patient.setWard(patientGenerator.getRandomWard());
        template.update("UPDATE tbl_inpatients SET ward = ?, department = ? WHERE id = ?", patient.getWard(),
                patient.getDepartment(), patient.getId());
        return patient;
    }

    public Patient dischargeRandomPatient() {
        Patient patient = getRandomInpatient();
        patient.setDischargeDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        insertFormerPatient(patient);
        template.update("DELETE FROM tbl_inpatients WHERE `instance`= ?", patient.getInstance());
        return patient;
    }

    public void insertFormerPatient(Patient patient) {
        template.update(
                "INSERT INTO tbl_formerpatients(`instance`, `id`, ward, department, admissionDate, dischargeDate) VALUES('"
                        + patient.getInstance() + "', '" + patient.getId() + "', '" + patient.getWard() + "', '"
                        + patient.getDepartment() + "', '" + patient.getAdmissionDateTime().toString() + "', '"
                        + patient.getDischargeDateTime().toString() + "')");
    }

    public int countPatients() {
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_patient";
        return template.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
    }

    public int countInpatients() {
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_inpatients";
        return template.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
    }

    public LocalDate parseBirthday(String birthday) {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(birthday);
        return localDate;

    }

    }
```

Comment: That's where single responsibility principle come to play. imagine a set of classes that only do one thing : e.g. : db classes only read and write from db and nothing else

Comment: If you want something lihter than an ORM (JPA, Hibernate, etc.), you should have a look at JOOQ - https://www.jooq.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an abstract class that contained your shared implementation code, and use the derived classes to implement those methods that change depending on implementation

```
 public abstract class AbstractPatientRepository
 {
      public void insertListOfPatients(List<Patient> allPatients) {
          for (Patient patient : allPatients) {
              insertPatient(patient);
      }

      public abstract Patient getRandomPatient();
 }

 public class PatientRepositoryMSSqlImpl extends AbstractPatientRepository
 {


     public Patient getRandomPatient() {
         String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl_patient ORDER BY NEWID()";
         Patient patient = (Patient) template.queryForObject(sql, new          PatientRowMapper());
         return patient;
     }

 }
```